# How to open telnet service in Windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, telnet

Just like the title, I tried to search the services list of Windows Server 2008 r2, but not find it. Should I install it with a installation file, or just need to switch telnet service toggle?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Install Telnet Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770501%28WS.10%29.aspx) article.

The relevant details:

> **To install Telnet Server on Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008**
>
> Start Server Manager. Click **Start**, right-click **Computer**, and then click **Manage**.
>
> If the **User Account Control** dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click **Continue**.
>
> In the **Features Summary** section, click **Add features**.
>
> On the **Select Features** page, select **Telnet Server**. You can also select **Telnet Client** if you want.
>
> Click **Next**, and then on the **Confirm Installation Options** page, click **Install**.
>
> On the **Installation Results** page, click **Close**.
>
> Close **Server Manager**.